# "Newest" questions in the [ios] tag is showing very old questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I was scrolling through the newest questions in [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), and I came upon a paradox I could not explain.

On [*this page*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios?page=6&sort=newest&pagesize=15) (***Note: you may need to go back a few pages to see the issue. 60 questions back at time of this writing***) of the newest questions in the tag, I get questions with asking dates ranging from `17 hours ago` to `Jan 21 '13`. The questions from 2013 have had no activity for a *long* time so there seems to be no reason for them to be on the list.

I have tried in multiple browsers and *can* reproduce the issue. I have also tried clearing cookies and caches.

However, the iOS app (which uses the API), does not exhibit the issue.

Comment: I see questions from 5 minutes ago to a couple of hours.

Comment: @Oded Skip to page 4, 5, and 6.

Comment: For me, the 15 question on that page range from "17 hours ago" to "May 10 2013"

Comment: For me, it jumps from "yesterday" to "Jun 20 '13" on the page 6/7 transition.

Comment: It's reverse-sorted by date.  Are you saying that, for some definition of "recent," we should just cut off the remaining questions in the list?  I don't think that's very useful.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm saying that there shouldn't be a question from more than a year ago on Page 7-8 of the "newest" list.

Comment: I don't see a time discontinuity in the list anywhere, although there do appear to be gaps where almost a month elapsed between questions.  I don't hit June 2013 until page 9.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Doesn't that count as a time discontinuity? We don't close and delete _that_ many questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios?page=8&sort=newest&pagesize=15) I get a range of questions from Jun 5, 2014 to Aug 30, 2013. There might be a _few_ missing there, don't you think?

Comment: The average interval between questions there appears to be about three weeks.  I suppose you could cross-check it with Data Explorer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Obviously this isn't the data explorer, but the iOS app (via the API) does not show any issues.

Comment: Include that bit of information in your question.

Comment: I guess it's similar to a question I asked several months ago: [Some old questions sneaks into the newest list of foreach tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226929/some-old-questions-sneaks-into-the-newest-list-of-foreach-tag). The problem was fixed before anyone provides an answer.

Comment: @YuHao Yep, seems to be the exact same thing.

Answer (score 4):

The issue appears to be fixed.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Server side caching. We have like, 5 levels of caching on our end...

Comment: @Oded What? You aren't using 6-level caching? Noob.